# add a jsp in all the jsps as header

Tags: java, html, css, jsp

I've a jsp that get the sum from a database. and i want to show this on every webpage the user opens in header. Here totally there are 8 pages, right from the time the index page is opened, let it be any page the user opens, the header should be fixed. My current code is as below.

**index.jsp**

```
 <body>
        <div class="header"><jsp:include page="counts.jsp" /></div>
        Title
    </body>
```

I get the count using the below files.
**counts.jsp**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript">
    function submitForm() {
        document.getElementById("form1").submit();
    }
    window.onload = submitForm;
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="GetTheCounts" method="get" id="form1"></form>

</body>
</html>
```

**MyServlet**

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        GetTheCountsDAO getTheCountsDAO = new GetTheCountsDAO();
        try {
            int excelCount = getTheCountsDAO.getTotalFromExcel();
            int DAOCount = getTheCountsDAO.getTotalFromDB();

            double getEffeciency = getTheCountsDAO.getEffeciency();

            request.setAttribute("DAOCount", DAOCount);
            request.setAttribute("excelCount", excelCount);
            request.setAttribute("effeciency", getEffeciency);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("counts1.jsp").forward(request, response);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**counts1.jsp**(which actually displays the counts)

```
<body>
    <div class="status">
        <span class="totalTime">Count is ${DAOCount}/${excelCount}</span> <span
            class="efficiency">${effeciency}</span>
    </div>

</body>
```

My DAO is returning the values as expected. Here the problem is, when I open the page (index.jsp). The text title is displayed and it is redirected to the next page instead of displaying the result in header itself. I'm thinking the concept like frames, where in the operation in frame is done there itself though it is redirected to some other page.

Below is my CSS for header.

```
.header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 5em;
}
```

please let me know how can i do it. I want the result to be displayed in the header section itself.

Thanks

Comment: Did not understand the question. But maybe the OP is looking for something like _apache-tiles_.

Answer (score -1):

add like this

`<%@ include file="header.jsp" %>`

Comment: Hi@ravi that's what I'm doing, here the difference is my page name is counts.jsp and you gave it as header.jsp

Comment: its sample .... what's wrong with name and you can pass any name in place of header.jsp

Comment: If you see my index.jsp code (the first block), this is already present there.

Comment: make a js file and in js file make function to get data from database and include that file in every jsp page and call that function in jsp file from js file   are you getting me ?